# regex to grab only one c-style multi-line comment immediately above a function

Tags: python, regex, parsing, comments, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to **grab the multi-line comment in some c code** that is above an arbitrary function using a regular expression. ONLY the comment **immediately above the function** and the function code itself is what i'm interested in. The comment will **definitely have a "\abc" in it** at the end (see snippet). I also don't really care if there is some more code or text below the function. A solution that contains some text/noise after the function is also acceptable.

I was thinking to grab the comment above the function via **lazy evaluation** but it's not quite working yet.

Here is my minimal example

```
import re

snippet = """
/*=================================================*
* THIS IS NOT THE COMMENT I WANT
*===============================================*/

/* THIS IS THE COMMENT I WANT.
* It should be able to have special characters like /,*.
* \\abc
*/
TEST(foo,bar){
    ...
}
"""

pattern = re.compile(r"(\/\*.)?\\abc.*", re.DOTALL)
search = pattern.search(snippet)
match = search.group(0)
print(match)
```

Output

```
\abc
*/
TEST(foo,bar){
    ...
}
```

Desired output

```
/* THIS IS THE COMMENT I WANT.
* It should be able to have special characters like /,*.
* \abc
*/
TEST(foo,bar){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/\*((?!\*/).)+\\abc.*`

This isn't the most readable but it works. It reads : `/*` then `\abc` then everything, but you can't match `*/` until you've matched the `\abc`. Or more accurately, `/*` then a number of characters that aren't `*/`, then `\abc`, then everything.

https://regex101.com/r/x1bXVg/3